# How to deal with multiple resource files for localization?

Tags: c#, localization, resource-files, satellite-assembly

I have a Project in which lot of resource strings are used. So, I keep them organized based on modules as a folder structure.

Like if Module A is a folder then under Module A i have the following files.

```
Module A

       ResourceFileA1.resx 
       ResourceFileA2.resx
       ResourceFileA1.de-DE.resx
       ResourceFileA2.de-DE.resx
```

and similar is the structure for module B.

But I just want to have a single class file or If not possible single wrapper class (for multiple classes pertaining to each resource file) to get the resource string. I am trying something like GetString(moduleA.ResourceFileA1.String)

I have tried something that is explained [here](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/10/21/localpt3.htm?page=1) But could not get it right. Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can use this: https://github.com/Jinjinov/wpf-localization-multiple-resource-resx-one-language

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention which version of the .NET framework you are restricted to, but assuming you are on at least .NET 2.0, you really shouldn't need to worry about manually managing your resource files.  Add a new resource file through Visual Studio, and you should see an auto-generated

```
ResourceFileA1.resx
```

and

```
ResourceFileA1.Designer.cs
```

The designer file should automatically create for you a compile-time reference to any resource items you put in your file such as:

```
moduleA.ResourceFileA1.YourStringKey
```

When you add new locales (.de-DE.resx, etc), moduleA.ResourceFileA1.YourStringKey should automatically refer to the right resource file based on Thread.CurrentCulture, however if you want you can pass it in explicitly by calling GetString

Comment: Thanks Nik Pinski. I am using .Net 4. I know it creates a designer class for each resource file. But this is a 1:1 mapping. And what I am looking for is a wrapper class as I do not want to call separate classes. So I need something like ResourceWrapper.GetString("Module.ResourceFile.String").

Comment: What I'm saying is that you don't need a separate Designer/Resource file combo.  You should be able to keep the localized (de-DE) resx file in the same directory as the default resx and Designer file, and it should work automatically

Answer (score 0):

The files you are showing are all local resources, designed to be accessible only by certain sections of your app. But you can also create global resources that can be used by all of your application's code. Assuming your app is an ASP.NET app these resources are in `App_GlobalResources`. See [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) page , particularly the sub-sections "Global Resource Files" and "Local Resource Files".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code below.

```
 [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    public static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager
    {

        get
        {
            resourceMan = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Ral." + Ral.ResourceFolderPath.GetClientKey + ".Asset.Resource", typeof(Resource).Assembly);
            return resourceMan;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

MSDN link works for me, since i was not following the Naming convention of resx files.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

it says "When you create resource files, you start by creating a base .resx file. For each language that you want to support, create a new file that has the same file name. But in the name, include the language or the language and culture (culture name). For a list of culture names, see the CultureInfo class. For example, you might create the following files:
 
WebResources.resx
The base resource file. This is the default (fallback) resource file.
WebResources.es.resx
A resource file for Spanish.
WebResources.es-mx.resx
 
A resource file for Spanish (Mexico) specifically.
WebResources.de.resx
A resource file for German."